# Is it permissible to collect counterfeit currency?

Tags: criminal-law

I know that making, or preparing to make, counterfeit bills is illegal.  I also know that if you use counterfeit currency you can have problems whether you were aware of it or not.

I would like to buy or acquire counterfeit bills to keep for educational research purposes.  Is there a legal way to do this?

I am interested mainly in Polish Złoty as well as Euro and Dollar bills.

Comment: It may pay to investigate whether you can register as a collector in your country.  Some locations make it a crime to **knowingly** possess counterfeit currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you can render the bills "unfit for circulation" then you should be ok.

One way to do this would be to laminate the bills in plastic, with an indellible label that states:  "COUNTERFEIT CURRENCY" or something to that effect.

Comment: Thank for comment. This is nice point of view. I am going to think more about this, especially to find different ways to marks them as unfit to circulation. Maybe printing on them such a message informing. You think this may be ok ? 
Is there any office or department I can make a question to be sure ?